# Weighting data with uneven groups

Tags: survey, unbalanced-classes, weights

I've seen that you can account for uneven amounts of respondents within different groups, but every example has the same amount starting. How do you handle if you have an uneven starting number per group going in? I conducted a survey on our new customers (Purchased in a certain time period) vs. current customers (purchased before that time period). So going into the survey, the new customer group had 5000 potential respondents and the current customer group had 100,000. In the end, both groups had a 2% response rate within their group. I want to compare the responses on each question with New vs. Current customers. Since they had such unequally distributed groups going into the survey, do I weight the data? Or, is it already equally distributed since they both have a 2% response rate?